# bootstrap responsive div display

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have two divs

```
<div class="container">
<div class="span6">
</div>
<div class="span6">
</div>
</div>
```

When the user uses mobile phone, the divs should be two rows one column instead of two columns one row.

How do I do that ?

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive):

> Turn on responsive CSS in your project by including the proper meta tag and additional stylesheet within the  of your document. If you've compiled Bootstrap from the Customize page, you need only include the meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also, use proper markup (`.spanX` should be inside `.row`):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6"></div>
    <div class="span6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For [fluid layout](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) you may use `.container-fluid` and `.row-fluid`.