# How to put a rounded div in a bootstrap site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">...</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div id="gallery">
        @foreach (var image in Model.Images)
        {
            <a href="@Url.Content(ViewBag.Path + image.filename)" data-lightbox="image-1">
                <img src="@Url.Action("Thumbnail", "Image", new { width = 120, height = 120, filename = @imagen.filename})" alt="@imagen.filename" />
            </a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to put make the div with id "gallery" as a rounded div and make it to be able to keep the aspect ratio when resizing the browser screen size.

Right now, if I put these lines of css code I get the div well rounded in a full screen mode. But when I resize it to a smaller screen size (mobile) I get the right side of the dive overlapped over the images in div:

```
border-radius: 25px;
border: 2px solid #8AC007;
padding: 20px;
```

How can I do to make a well responsive rounded div that contains images?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You will need your images to be responsive with '[img-responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)' class, (you will need to change the width and height elements to just a max-width (or height) and you might want to check out [this S.O. post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962700/bootstrap-responsive-div-display) about managing responsive divs. 
Then just keep the responsive image inside the responsive div, and you should be all set.

```
<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row">Your divs > Your images</div></div>
```

Comment: Ok. This seems to be the answer. But now, I get the images vertically when full size screen. I want to get hotizontally the images when reduce the screen size.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want your images to display horizontally, but they are currently displaying vertically? To make them appear horizontally, you just need to set a{display: inline-block}, or with Bootstrap, you can do <ul class="list-inline"> then set your @foreach to display <li><a>. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What I want is that in a full screen desktop mode images display vertically and when the screen mode is mobile (reducing the browser size for simulating it) images display horizontally.

Comment: Have you tried using a media query for that? For example: @media(max-width: 480px){a{display: inline-block;}

Comment: Where do I put that line of media query? In css file?

Comment: I would recommend putting it in your CSS file, yes. Although, you can also put it in a <style></style> tag at the top of your HTML. You can learn more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries, or just google media queries - there are 1000's of examples out there. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: @media(max-width: 480px){a{display: inline-block;} doesn't work.

Comment: So, you have a couple of options (This is basic CSS. You just change regular CSS styles in the media query block based on screen size), but first - can I ask why you want to display images vertically (top to bottom) on wide screen, and horizontally (left to right) on small screen? Wouldn't it make more sense the other way around? In any case... I'm sure you have your reasons. So, if inline-block is not inlining your blocks, just try something like 'display: inline; float: left;'. That should work. (I am assuming you are not using ul class="list-inline" here).

Comment: I will try this. But I have another issue to solve. Also I want to center what there is inside <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> whether it is diplayed in a big screen size or small screen size. Right now, if I use a smaller screen, all contained in that div is aligned to the left. I would like to center in that div.